# Python 3.4 - Pandas - Extract Rows Based on Column of another Dataframe Including Duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two input dataframes in the format of:

```
Word    colA colB colC ID
python   A     B    C   1
word     D     E    F   1
of       G     H    I   1
python   J     K    L   2
is       M     N    O   2
of       P     Q    R   3
```

and another one in the format of:

```
V1       V2    V3   V4
the     0.1   0.2  0.3
python  0.4   0.5  0.6
excel   0.6   0.7  0.8
is      0.9   0.10 0.6
access  0.7   0.5  0.6
of      0.5   1.2  7.8
tell    0.9   3.2  4.5
pandas  0.5   0.4  0.3
```

Lets call the first dataframe df1 and the second one df2.

I want to know how to subset df2, based on V1, that have the same terms as df1['Word']. If the term in V1 has no matches in df1['Word'], I would like the rows to be filled with zeros. Also, another key point is that I would like to INCLUDE duplicates. I would also like to copy the 'ID' column to the df2 dataframe.

My expected output would be in this format:

```
   V1    V2    V3   V4  ID
python  0.4   0.5  0.6  1
word    0.0   0.0  0.0  1
of      0.5   1.2  7.8  1
python  0.4   0.5  0.6  2
is      0.9   0.10 0.6  2
of      0.5   1.2  7.8  3
```

I am able to successfully identify and subset terms  in the output dataframe without the duplicates showing. But including duplicates of terms has provided to be somewhat of a challenge to me. I would also need help in successfully copying the df1['ID'] column to the end of the output dataframe as well.

I would appreciate any help that I can get.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

- first rename column `Word` and select only necessary columns by subset `[[]]`
- [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join
- replace all `NaN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)
- last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) if order of columns is important

---

```
df = (pd.merge(df1.rename(columns={'Word':'V1'})[['V1', 'ID']], 
               df2, on='V1', how='left')
        .fillna(0)
        .reindex(columns=['V1','V2','V3','V4','ID']))
print (df)
       V1   V2   V3   V4  ID
0  python  0.4  0.5  0.6   1
1    word  0.0  0.0  0.0   1
2      of  0.5  1.2  7.8   1
3  python  0.4  0.5  0.6   2
4      is  0.9  0.1  0.6   2
5      of  0.5  1.2  7.8   3
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out. One quick question before I do, is there a way to drop the columns from 'Word', 'colA -colC' automatically from the dataframe? Or would I need to drop them manually after the resultant dataframe is created?

Comment: I've noted your change, I will try it out. Thank you

Comment: @VinayAshokkumar - good question, finally need only columns `V1` and `ID`, so not necessary drop them.

Comment: this seems to work, but I need to extend this to a much bigger dataset. Let's say I have 50 columns from V1 to V50. In your statement in the .reindex() section, is there a way to select a range of column variables? Something similar to V1-V50? Or do I have to list each one of the columns from 'V1', 'V2,.....,V50, which can be quite tedious. Thank you.

Comment: No, use list comprehenison for it `c = ['V{}'.format(x) for x in range(1, 51)]`

Comment: And then columns = c, Within reindex()?

Comment: @VinayAshokkumar, yes, `.reindex(columns=c+ ['ID'])`